# How to get custom signals from a Qt dialog box

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4

I have a QDialog with 3 buttons - Apply, OK and Cancel. In the __init__ method of the Dialogbox,  I am connecting the OK and Cancel using the following:

```
buttonBox.accepted.connect( self.accept )
buttonBox.rejected.connect( self.reject )
```

In my main form, I am able to run a method (addNameToSandbox) for the OK signal using

```
self.__nameDialog.accepted.connect(self.__addNameToSandbox)
```

However, I want the Apply button to do the same but keep the child Dialog box open (as opposed to the OK button which closes it). How can I get that signal on the main window?

I have a method within the child dialog that I am able to run when Apply is clicked, but how to trigger an action in the main form with that, I have no idea.

```
buttonBox.button( QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply ).clicked.connect( self.add )
```

I've tried using some of the other signals like finished, but I can't figure that one out either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a signal in the dialog and connect it to the clicked of the apply button, and then use a signal to connect it in your main form:

```
class YourDialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    applyClicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(YourDialog, self).__init__(parent):
        # ...
        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)
        apply_button = buttonBox.button(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Apply)
        apply_button.clicked.connect(self.applyClicked)
        # ...
```

```
self.__nameDialog.accepted.connect(self.__addNameToSandbox)
self.__nameDialog.applyClicked.connect(self.__applyfunc)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `QtCore.pyqtSignal applied` as a class variable and then fire it up with `self.applied.emit()`

Then you'll be able to use it:

```
self.__nameDialog.applied.connect(self.__applyPressed)
```